# Unable to print array outside foreach loop

Tags: php

```
 $val = array();
 foreach ($value as $key) {
        $nested = $this->Mdl_mymodel->arr($key); 
        if($nested != NULL) {
                    $n = 0;
                    foreach ($nested as $nest) {
                            $n++;
                            $val[$n] = $nest->num; 
                    }
        }
         else {
                    $val = '';
            }

        print_r($val);  
}
print_r($val);
```

Here $val inside the loop is printed but outside it is empty. I think i am missing something. Please help!
Note: I am using codeigniter.

Comment: maybe you are hitting the else on the last iteration?

Comment: you should explain a bit more if you want some help, what is `$value`, where `$key` is used in surrounding `foreach` ? ... what returning `$this->Mdl_mymodel->arr()` ... etc etc

Comment: I am able to print $nested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$val = array();
foreach ($value as $key) {
    $nested = $this->Mdl_mymodel->arr(); 
    if($nested != NULL) {
        $n = 0;
        foreach ($nested as $nest) {
            $n++;
            $val[$n] = $nest->num;
        }
    }
    else {
        // $val = ''; Commented this line because you have already 
        // initialized $val. If you do not get records,
        // it will return as blank array.
    }
    print_r($val);  
}
print_r($val);
```